# Can Detect Magic reveal creatures benefiting from the Invisibility spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility

The wording concerning the Detect Magic spell causes some issues when thinking about invisible creatures. All of my groups in the past have, as far as I know, allowed detecting Invisible creatures with detect magic, as it allows you to see the effects of spells on creatures.

However, re-reading it, I noticed that it says "any visible creature or object". Taking only this line into context, it seems to imply that you need to be able to see the creature in the first place to detect any magical trace on it.

However, the final line of the spell seems to indirectly imply that you CAN detect creatures you cannot see. The spell can pierce many surfaces, so you would be able to detect a magically affected creature even if it has total cover from you, i.e: it is not visible to you.

I've also seen detect magic used to see the invisible orb created by scrying. The spell says that it is visible to those that can see invisible objects, but its nature as a temporary created magical object would suggest that it should have a glow when seen through detect magic.

Perhaps Detect Magic explicitly does not work if a creature is invisible? In that case you would be able to see magical effects through walls of stone or dirt, but not if the affected creature or object is invisible. Even though you already cannot see it due to cover! This is what I see as the literal interpretation, am I wrong? Or what is the correct interpretation?

In a less RAW sense, is it unreasonable to allow Detect Magic to see through these effects (when caused by spells) as a homebrew rule?

While not in sage advice, [this tweet from the rules lead, Jeremy Crawford clarifies](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/879755273463709696?lang=en) that Detect Magic can sense the presence of any spell unless another effect, such as Nystul's Magic Aura, says otherwise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the Detect Magic spell show a glowing outline around an invisible creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159921/does-the-detect-magic-spell-show-a-glowing-outline-around-an-invisible-creature)

Comment: That question is related but I don't think it exactly answers my concerns. I mentioned the paragraph they quote in their solution already, it's just that it seems weird when put into context with other info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [*Detect Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) allows the caster to know there is a magical effect within 30 feet of them visible or not.

> For the duration, you sense the presence of magic within 30 feet of you.

Spells do what they say and the caster gains this benefit.  Sensing the presence of something in this case is distinct from being able to see, hear, or otherwise perceive it with a conventional physical perception.

> If you sense magic in this way (the extra magical perception granted by the spell), you can use your action to see a faint aura around any visible creature or object in the area that bears magic, and you learn its school of magic, if any.

When sensed in this way, the caster can take their action to see an aura around a visible creature or object.  Non-visible (invisible or completely obscured) creatures or objects do not satisfy the predicate and do not get this aura around them in the vison of the caster.

### An invisible object or creature within 30 feet of the caster

The caster would get the information that they "sense magic within 30 feet of them". They would also get the information that they see no auras when they take an action to look for them if there weren't another source of magic in the vicinity.

### Location

The spell does not give the caster the location of the sources.  If they are visible, the caster can take an action to see the auras.  If not, the caster is merely alerted to their presence.  There is still a ~2700 square foot area for the caster to search to discover the source, if it's not visibly apparent.

### Occluded sources

As the spell states, some material will block the effect of the spell. For example, a want wrapped in a sheet of lead will not alert the caster that there is magic in the area of affect. A sheet of lead and the other material mentioned in the spell description also block line of sight, so the aura aspect is equally as moot.

### Indistinguishable sources

The spell does not say it permits the caster to know how many distinct sources there are nor can it tell if a source with an aura is the only source they're detecting.  So an invisible and visible source of magic in the area of effect is likely to be mistaken for just the visible one.

Comment: I think that makes sense, thank you! I missed that the 30ft radius detection does not specify visible creatures, but the aura vision does.

Comment: This (or some reworking of this) would be an excellent answer to the linked question as well.